# HTML Entities for Back Arrow

Tags: html, css, html-entities

Check this image...

[image]

I want to make a back arrow like this using HTML Entities. Are there any available?

Comment: You can use css for creating this type of back arrow

Comment: [`&#9664;`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25c0/index.htm)

Comment: if your page is in utf-8 character set, you don't need it as an entity; just send the actual character.

Comment: You might find this page helpful:  http://shapecatcher.com/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is real fun :D I just did [this](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=html+back+arrow+entity&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&gws_rd=cr&ei=qnxeUof9GMPirAf7r4DgBw#q=html+left+triangle+entity&rls=org.mozilla:en-US%3Aofficial) and I got the answser, its - `&#x25c0;`.

[Reference](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25c0/index.htm) - [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zd2JA/)

Answer (score 8):

The answer from @Mr.Alien probably addresses what you really wanted to know. I will answer the question that you actually asked:

There is no HTML entity for a character resembling your image. This does not mean that such characters cannot be used; just the absence of defined entities.

The classic HTML concept of entity reference is being replaced by the “named character reference” in HTML5. Interpreted as relating to them, the answer depends on whether your image is interpreted as “◀” U+25C0 BLACK LEFT-POINTING TRIANGLE or as “◂” U+25C2 BLACK LEFT-POINTING SMALL TRIANGLE. They are very similar, typically identical in shape but in different sizes. The former has a named character reference, `&blacktriangleleft;`, in HTML5.

However, using the such references (beyond those defined in HTML 4) is unwise: they have limited browser coverage, and they provide no real benefit over using the numeric character references `&#x25c0;` and `&#x25c2;` (or their decimal counterparts) or the actual characters.

Note that these characters are present in some fonts only. This problem does not depend on the way the characters are entered in a document. For more on this, see my [Guide to using special characters in HTML](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/characters.html). (This is where CSS becomes relevant. CSS is totally irrelevant to the basic question about including a character in HTML.)

Answer (score 4):

You can use its decimal code:

`&#9664;`

◀

Answer (score 1):

CSS can be used to create an arrow with out the need of an image.  You can use borders to create it.

[CSS Arrow Example](http://jsfiddle.net/SbgTw/1/)

```
.arrow-right {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 30px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 30px solid transparent;
    border-left: 30px solid green;
}
```

[Reference](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/)

Comment: @ Casey Jeremiason ha ha ha, i did not give any down vote. before answering u need to reed the question properly, Question was for HTML entities any way +1 for u

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I prefer this back arrow.

### ←

It has a nice and simple HTML entity too: `&larr;`.

This is for all the people who come here searching for a back arrow, but don't just want a triangle.

http://htmlarrows.com/arrows/left-arrow/

Answer (score -2):

Press `Alt 17` on your keyboard manually to get the arrow that you are looking for.

**For Instance**

```
<div>◄ (alt 17 pressed manually)</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This only works in (some versions of) Windows and does not answer the question.

Comment: It does @JukkaK.Korpela - If you press Alt 17 inside your tags where you want the arrow, it will give you the output that the OP is looking for.

Comment: The question says “usi[ng] HTML Entities”.

Comment: I edited my answer keeping HTML Entities. You can have a look - @JukkaK.Korpela